# It is possible to cange the Twig Cache from Filesystem to Memcache?

Tags: twig, slim

i use Slim Framework 3 with Twig.
It works great but the Cache (compiled Templates) use the Filesystem to store the compiled Templates.
It is possible to speed up this by using Memcached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [OPCache](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.opcache.php), you have already great performance.

You can do a custom cache but it's not documented, see [this PR](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/pull/1812) and [this issue](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/728). Anyway, I don't think you will have better performance than PHP file with a good configured OPCache.

Comment: The basic thinking is that get data from memory is always much faster than reading from Harddrive.
I will take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but OPCache is stocked on the RAM.